# Adding extra lines to the If[condition,t,f] command

Tags: core-language, conditional, coding-style

I wish that the Mathematica documentation for the If command showed examples that have more than one statement for the t and f responses.

All three of these work:

No parentheses or braces:

```
Module[{x, y, z},
 If[3 === 4,
  x = 1;
  y = 2;
  z = x + y,
  x = 5;
  y = 9;
  z = x + y];
 Print[z]]
```

Use parentheses:

```
Module[{x, y, z},
 If[3 === 4,
  (x = 1;
   y = 2;
   z = x + y),
  (x = 5;
   y = 9;
   z = x + y)];
 Print[z]]
```

Use braces:

```
Module[{x, y, z},
 If[3 === 4,
  {x = 1;
   y = 2;
   z = x + y},
  {x = 5;
   y = 9;
   z = x + y}];
 Print[z]]
```

All give output 14.

Is it OK to use each of these three? If so, what do users prefer?

Comment: The first and second are identical. The third is different in that it returns the list `{z}` (Also note that you generally don't need the `Print` statement at the end. A plain `z` will do if you're working interactively.). All three work by making a `CompoundExpression`. (`a;b;c` really is just `CompoundExpression[a, b, c]`). You only need parens to resolve ambiguity. The first is therefore probably the cleanest. The third is definitely not what you want. (unless you *are* trying to build a list).

Comment: @MB1965 Nice answer. But you said `The third is different in that it returns the list {z}`. I think you meant to say `The third is different in that it returns the list {z} if you don't use the Print command.` Still, I really appreciate this answer.

Comment: I mean the `If` returns that. The `Print` command is really pretty much meaningless here. (By which I mean leaving it out will not change what you see in any way -- except that you'll have and `"Output"` cell instead of `"Print"` cell).

Answer (score 2):

I did not initially post an answer because I don't use a single format for `If` statements and it is rare that I use them to perform a series of Sets.  If I did I would probably formulate it more like this:

```
Module[{x, y, z},
  {x, y} = If[3 === 4, {1, 2}, {5, 9}];
  z = x + y
]
```

If you prefer something more along the lines of UnchartedWorks' answer I see no need to pass parameters, e.g.:

```
Module[{x, y, z, f, g},
  f[] := (x = 1; y = 2; z = x + y);
  g[] := (x = 5; y = 9; z = x + y);
  If[3 === 4, f[], g[]]
]
```

By convension I use `f[]` rather than bare `f` for any parameter-free subroutine as among other things this lets one pass the name `f` without triggering unwanted evaluation.

Comment: I didn't know his/her intention, that's why I refactored the code without any assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Module[{x, y, z, f, g, h},
 f[x, y, z] := {x = 1; y = 2; z = x + y};
 g[x, y, z] := {x = 5; y = 9; z = x + y};
 h[x, y, z] := If[3 === 4, f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z]] // First // Print;
 h[x, y, z]]
```